# Ubuntu 20.04 Default terminal user doesnt have write group access

Tags: command-line, users, groups

I am trying to add user123 to group group123. I used the command usermod -a -G group123 user123. When I change to that user it is apart of the correct groups.
When I open the terminal and run $users it shows I am user123 however when I run groups it shows I am not apart of group123. I need to run $sudo su user123 to have the correct groups. How can I make it that when I open the terminal I dont have to switch to user123.

Answer (score 3):

Group membership is applied at `login` time, from the `/etc/group` file.

To make use of the new group, logout/login, or, for testing, read `man newgrp`.